# Integrate REST API with glassfish

Tags: rest, glassfish

I have an application that runs on glassfish server. This application has a background thread that will run until the application is shutdown.
I want to create a REST API that can call the destroy method for the background thread so that the background thread will shut down upon getting a GET request from outside the application. How can I integrate this REST API with the glassfish server ?

Comment: What do you mean by "background thread"? Is there a reason you aren't using an `@ApplicationScoped` CDI bean or maybe an EJB? I think there are probably better ways to achieve your goal.

Comment: About the REST API, though, a JAX-RS class with an `@GET` annotated method will work.